# prebuilt scripts for common tables such as contacts, logins, etc?

Tags: sql, postgresql, open-source

Please understand that I'm effectively a SQL noob even though I know a few tricks here and there, so this may seem silly.

Do open source SQL scripts exist for PostgreSQL?  If so, where can they be found?

For example, it seems silly to recreate a contacts database when someone else has almost surely built a "perfect" one that anyone could use & customize already.

Again, please forgive my noobity, as I'm all but sure that my vocabulary is incorrect.

Comment: Somebody may have created a contacts table that is perfect for their requirments, but your requirements may not be the same.

Comment: @DanBracuk right, but with js/jquery & server-sides, there are libraries that can do common tasks with customization.  does such a thing exist with SQL?  if so, what is it called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are publickly available DB dumps with geo data (all kinds of maps), phone and address books for different countries, etc. Also there are prebuilt schemas, used by some web (and not only web) frameworks.

But all of them are built for different purposes and there is no perfect solution.

Comment: thank you!  so what i'm looking for is a "schema"?

Comment: @Gracchus Yes. Schema is a collection of tables, functions, keys and other things a DB can have. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema